# Generating Digital Signature

Tags: vb.net, digital-signature

I wanted to generate digital signature in my asp.net application based on some value 
like date of birth. what is the way  to do that ? i am using vb.net

Comment: When you say digital signature...what do you mean exactly? What is it you are trying to accomplish? Take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decide that you really do want what that Wikipedia article talks about, then see the [SignedXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml.aspx) class in the [System.Security.Cryptography.Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.aspx) namespace.

---

Note that this isn't the only way to work with Digital Signature in .NET - it's just the part I've worked with before.